# Trying to run pylint in Windows 7 and Python 3.3

Tags: windows-7, pylint, python-3.3

I knew this general question is not new, but it seems my personal problem with it.

I try to install pylint under Windows 7 for Python 3.3 (Yes I know it is not supported, but I know it is possible - because a colleague of mine did it, but sadly his workaround for known issues was not working on my pc - and he has Windows 8 ...)

At this time I have installed python 3.3, and first tried to install pylint via pip, this failed.

A search and some talks with my colleague brought this answer:
[No luck pip-installing pylint for Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772824/no-luck-pip-installing-pylint-for-python-3)

I managed to install pylint with these instructions, but one of the dependecies (logilab-astng) failed.

I checked the setup.py script and realised that the "2to3" conversion did not run on my machine (I think due to path problems) - I reconfigured the conversion and it ran.

Afterwards all installation processes (pylint, logilab-astng, logilab-common) exited "successful" - but if I start pylint I got these message:

```
G:\Path\to\project>pylint --rcfile .\pylint.rc modulename
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\Scripts\pylint-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pylint==0.27.0', 'console_scripts', 'pylint')()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\pylint-0.27.0-py3.3.egg\pylint\__init__.py", line 21, in run_pylint
    Run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\pylint-0.27.0-py3.3.egg\pylint\lint.py", line 991, in __init__
    linter.check(args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\pylint-0.27.0-py3.3.egg\pylint\lint.py", line 587, in check
    self.check_astng_module(astng, walker, rawcheckers)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\pylint-0.27.0-py3.3.egg\pylint\lint.py", line 666, in check_astng_module
    walker.walk(astng)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\pylint-0.27.0-py3.3.egg\pylint\utils.py", line 600, in walk
    self.walk(child)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\pylint-0.27.0-py3.3.egg\pylint\utils.py", line 597, in walk
    cb(astng)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\pylint-0.27.0-py3.3.egg\pylint\checkers\variables.py", line 510, in visit_import
    module = next(node.infer_name_module(parts[0]))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\bases.py", line 304, in wrapped
    for res in _func(node, context, **kwargs):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\inference.py", line 181, in infer_imp
ort
    yield self.do_import_module(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\mixins.py", line 117, in do_import_mo
dule
    return mymodule.import_module(modname, level=level)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\scoped_nodes.py", line 342, in import
_module
    return MANAGER.astng_from_module_name(absmodname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\manager.py", line 136, in astng_from_
module_name
    return self.astng_from_file(filepath, modname, fallback=False)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\manager.py", line 107, in astng_from_
file
    return ASTNGBuilder(self).file_build(filepath, modname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\builder.py", line 129, in file_build
    node = self.string_build(data, modname, path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\builder.py", line 135, in string_buil
d
    module = self._data_build(data, modname, path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\builder.py", line 162, in _data_build

    module = self.rebuilder.visit_module(node, modname, package)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\rebuilder.py", line 616, in visit_mod
ule
    newnode.body = [self.visit(child, newnode) for child in node.body]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\rebuilder.py", line 616, in <listcomp
>
    newnode.body = [self.visit(child, newnode) for child in node.body]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\rebuilder.py", line 137, in visit
    return self._visit_meths[cls](node, parent)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\rebuilder.py", line 471, in visit_fun
ction
    newnode.body = [self.visit(child, newnode) for child in node.body]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\rebuilder.py", line 471, in <listcomp
>
    newnode.body = [self.visit(child, newnode) for child in node.body]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\rebuilder.py", line 137, in visit
    return self._visit_meths[cls](node, parent)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\rebuilder.py", line 450, in visit_for

    newnode.body = [self.visit(child, newnode) for child in node.body]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\rebuilder.py", line 450, in <listcomp
>
    newnode.body = [self.visit(child, newnode) for child in node.body]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\rebuilder.py", line 137, in visit
    return self._visit_meths[cls](node, parent)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\rebuilder.py", line 540, in visit_if
    newnode.body = [self.visit(child, newnode) for child in node.body]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\rebuilder.py", line 540, in <listcomp
>
    newnode.body = [self.visit(child, newnode) for child in node.body]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\rebuilder.py", line 137, in visit
    return self._visit_meths[cls](node, parent)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\rebuilder.py", line 391, in visit_dis
card
    newnode.value = self.visit(node.value, newnode)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\rebuilder.py", line 141, in visit
    visit_method = getattr(self, visit_name)
AttributeError: 'TreeRebuilder3k' object has no attribute 'visit_yieldfrom'
```

I'm looking forward to your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that logilab-astng, which hold the ast representation used by pylint, doesn't yet support "yieldfrom" nodes which have been introduced in python 3.3.

You may want to try the patch below, it should fix the problem:

```
diff --git a/rebuilder.py b/rebuilder.py
--- a/rebuilder.py
+++ b/rebuilder.py
@@ -877,10 +877,12 @@ class TreeRebuilder3k(TreeRebuilder):
             newnode.handlers = [self.visit(child, newnode) for child in node.handlers]
             newnode.orelse = [self.visit(child, newnode) for child in node.orelse]
         newnode.set_line_info(newnode.last_child())
         return newnode

+    def visit_yieldfrom(self, node, parent):
+        return self.visit_yield(node, parent)

 if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
     TreeRebuilder = TreeRebuilder3k
```

Comment: The patch removed the posted problem, but another occur: KeyError: ('cherrypy.process', None) in logilab_astng-0.24.2-py3.3.egg\logilab\astng\manager.py", line 164, in file_from_module_name

Comment: Should I open a new question for this new state? Oder just edit the question above?